# How to compare dates in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following simple setup, where fromDate and toDate are strings on the format "YYYY-MM-DD":

```
class SomeType(Base):
    date = Column(DateTime)

def findAll(fromDate, toDate):
    return session.query(SomeType).filter(SomeType.date >= fromDate, SomeType.date <= toDate).all()
```

The problem is that it doesn't find what I want it to find unless I modify the input dates like this:

```
def findAll(fromDate, toDate):
    fromDate = fromDate + " 00:00"
    toDate = toDate + " 24:00"
    return session.query(SomeType).filter(SomeType.date >= fromDate, SomeType.date <= toDate).all()
```

But that doesn't look good. Any ideas on how I can do this the right way?

Comment: What is wrong with the first sample? What do you mean by "it doesn't find what I want to find"? What, specifically, doesn't it find?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects instead of strings for `fromDate`, `toDate`?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def findAll(fromDate, toDate):
    fromDate = datetime.strptime(fromDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    toDate = datetime.strptime(toDate, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=1)
    return session.query(SomeType).filter(
        SomeType.date >= fromDate,
        SomeType.date < toDate).all()
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your `SomeType.date` column is not simple `date`, but is `datetime` column, so it contains also a time component.

This type mismatch is the cause of your problem. If this is the case then following should work:

`session.query(SomeType).filter(func.date(SomeType.date) >= fromDate, func.date(SomeType.date) <= toDate).all()`

where we basically `cast` `datetime` to `date` using [`DATE(...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function of MySql.

*However, I would probably also prefer working with `date(time)` data types instead of strings. You are just lucky that most databases implicitly allow parsing of ISO-compliant string representations of DATEs.*

Comment: Also needs `from sqlalchemy import func`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but while trying to find my answer, I found datetime.combine

you can do

```
select(SomeTable)
.filter( SomeTable.datetime_issued >= datetime.combine(start_date, time.min),
         SomeTable.datetime_issued <= datetime.combine(end_date, time.max))
```

datetime.combine will combine **date** and **time** into **datetime**

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine

When combining, you should use **time.min**, **time.max** which will give you min and max time

```
print(combine(date.today(), time.min), combine(date.today(), time.max))
```

This will print

> 2022-10-14 00:00:00, 2022-10-14 23:59:59.999999

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.max