# SQLAlchemy Comparing dates

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, orm

Is there a way to put a condition in a query where I want records whose subscription is ongoing ?
What I want to do is essentially this:

```
todays_date = date.today()
table.columns.startDate <= todays_date <= table.columns.endDate
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

The date types of both todays_date and startDate and endDate are the same. >>> `<class 'datetime.date'>`

I can perform this operation if I draw out all records in a query and use a for loop to implement the date condition at every record. But I want to write a more efficient script with a single more complicated query. So is there a function/method I can use for this?

Comment: As mentioned in the [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying): "For example, to query for users named “ed” with a full name of “Ed Jones”, you can call `filter()` twice, which joins criteria using `AND`"

Comment: Some entries in the date column are NoneTypes values. To my knowledge it would throw an error no matter what the query is. Is there a way to bypass the nonetypes other than entering a for loop if statement construct (going record by record) ?

Comment: Null values in the column will not necessarily throw an error, but they will affect the search results. For example, if you use a null `end_date` to signify an ongoing event then using `start_date <= '2020-12-19' AND end_date >= '2020-12-19'` will never return those rows. Instead, you would need to use `start_date <= '2020-12-19' AND (end_date >= '2020-12-19' OR end_date IS NULL)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare dates in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301934/how-to-compare-dates-in-sqlalchemy)